# acquireTokenSilent failing

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I can log in fine using loginPopup and get a valid token back. However if I refresh the page and try to retrieve the same token using acquireTokenSilent I get the following error:

```
This application does not have sufficient permissions 
against this web resource to perform the operation
```

Shouldn't the session persist? Or do I need to do something to achieve this?

The scope I am requesting is currently:

```
https://MY_TENANT.onmicrosoft.com/MY_APP/read openid offline_access
```

I've tried a few different scope options but no luck so far

Comment: Can you verify that the token you retrieve avter the loginPopup call is an access_token and that it contains the read scope for your app?

Comment: You are exactly right. The token I had was an id Token and was configured to access the wrong application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loginPopup **probably returns an id token** and would also fail if you requst an access token. Ensure your UI app has read permission for the app you requesting the access.

Comment: how can I see that my UI app has enough permissions?